# Multine line label on settings

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-settings

I would like to crate a settings Activity with items with Title and subtitle.

I've checked a lot in documentation and even other posts here and people say it's not possible... android default settings page has a lot of it:
 [image]

sorry for the picture in portuguese, but what is written there doesn't matter, the point is the settings page built on android has plenty of titile/subtitle items (and it happens in many other screens)

I would like to achieve it using android default `Preference` api. is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. One fast solution is the following (that might be improvied and tuned according your needs):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.settings_fragment, new PrefsFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        public PrefsFragment(){}

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settings_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.vb.myapplication.SettingsActivity$PrefsFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="keyCategory"
        android:title="titleCategory">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="keyCheckPreference"
            android:title="titlePreference"
            android:summary="summaryPreference"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: I've all this set, all i COULDN'T FIND was `android:summary` thankyou very much.  and sorry for making you write so much for getting this small field